# SnipMate Stops Working When Adding More Plugins

Tags: vim, gvim, vim-plugins

I am using Vim 7.3 with Pathogen on Windows, I have Pathogen setup in `~/vimfiles/autoload/pathogen.vim` and SnipMate `~/vimfiles/bundle/snipmate.vim/`. SnipMate works fine when it is the only plugin loaded by Pathogen, whenever I add other plugins SnipMate seems to no longer work.

```
filetype off
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
filetype plugin indent on
set nocompatible
```

That is the top of my `_vimrc` file and other plugins seem to load fine when I add them. It's just SnipMate stops working and I was wondering if anyone else had encountered this issue, and maybe has a solution?

Comment: `set nocompatible` should come first, I think. How do you add other plugins, in the `plugin` folder or in `bundle`?

Comment: I extracted them into their own folders in `~/vimfiles/bundle/`.

Comment: That's the normal way. You didn't list the other plugins you are trying to install. You didn't say if there were error messages or simply nothing. Try installing one plugin at a time, at each new plugin relaunch Vim and check if snipMate works. Does any of the other plugins use the `tab` key? snipMate and superTab are known to be incompatible because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked down the issue and have solved it. I was using https://github.com/hallison/vim-ruby-sinatra which has a `snippets` folder containing a `ruby-sinatra.snippets` file for `snipmate.vim`. Moving this folder into the `snipmate.vim` snippets folder seemed to resolve all the issues I was having.